# Implementing a HTTP web request in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular

I have been following the Angular2 example here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/

I have got to the end where I have put in place the promise for the mock heroes. I want to go further though and try to put in place a http request to get the heroes list from a 3rd party source.

Say, for example, I have set up a web url http://pastebin.com/raw/2mEEPeUs which returns the list of heroes as json in the format given in the example.

What is the best way to implement this?

From looking at [Angular 2, Getting Data Out of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984710/angular-2-getting-data-out-of-service) I thought this might be as easy as updating the following:

hero.service.ts

```
import {Hero} from './hero';
import {HEROES} from './mock-heroes';
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
constructor(public http: Http){}
  getHeroes(){
    return this.http.request('http://pastebin.com/raw/2mEEPeUs')
        .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

and

app.component.js

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getHeroes().subscribe(
    res => this.heroes = res,
    err => this.logError(err));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this plunker I created an example with http request: http://plnkr.co/edit/qXwLNh6UHacmHhji80VR

For me there where 3 hard things:

1. You should add  to your index.html
2. You need to add the HTTP_PROVIDERS to the injector in boot.ts
3. You need to import rxjs/Rx into the hero service

The code looks like:
boot.ts

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";
import {App} from "./app.component";
import {HeroService} from "./hero.service";

bootstrap(App, [HeroService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

Hero-service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import construct = Reflect.construct;
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {


    constructor(private _http : Http) {

    }


    public getHeroesAsObservable () {
        // reactive programming
        // https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754
        //http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angular2-observables-http-separating-services-components/

        return this._http.get('heroes').map(res => res.json());

    }

}
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HeroDetailComponent} from "./hero-detail.component";
import {HeroService} from "./hero.service";
import {OnInit} from "angular2/core";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles:[`
      .heroes {list-style-type: none; margin-left: 1em; padding: 0; width: 10em;}
      .heroes li { cursor: pointer; position: relative; left: 0; transition: all 0.2s ease; }
      .heroes li:hover {color: #369; background-color: #EEE; left: .2em;}
      .heroes .badge {
        font-size: small;
        color: white;
        padding: 0.1em 0.7em;
        background-color: #369;
        line-height: 1em;
        position: relative;
        left: -1px;
        top: -1px;
      }
      .selected { background-color: #EEE; color: #369; }
    `],
    template: `
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <ul class="heroes">
            <li *ngFor="#hero of heroes"
                (click)="onSelectHero(hero)"
                [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero">
                <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></hero-detail>
        `,
    directives:[HeroDetailComponent],
    //providers:[HeroService]
})
export class App implements OnInit{
    public title = 'Tours of Heroes';
    public heroes;
    public selectedHero : Hero;

    constructor(private _heroesService : HeroService) {

    }

    ngOnInit () {
        //this._heroesService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);

        var observable = this._heroesService.getHeroesAsObservable()
            .subscribe(
                data => this.heroes = data,
                err => console.log('ERROR!!!', err)
            );

    }

    onSelectHero (hero : Hero) {
        this.selectedHero = hero;
    }

}
```

local Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tour of heroes tutorial Angular 2</title>


    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
            packages: {
                src: {
                    format: 'register',
                    defaultExtension: 'js'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('src/boot')
                .then(null, console.error);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>


<html>
```

Adding an async pipe is a good idea!
Hope the plunker works for you

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the `async` pipe to display the observable in the template. This way you don't have to manage the subscription by your own:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngRepeat="hero of heroes | async">{{hero.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes = this.getHeroes();  
  }
}
```

This answer could also give you some additional hints about the way to implement HTTP requests in services and use them from components:

- [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-a-service-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948)

Hope it helps you,
Thierry